# How Can Manage Multiple Preloader On One Website?

Tags: jquery, ajax, preloader

I have two preloaders in my website.

One is using id (#jqueryLoader) and some of the pages are using this class (.sec1).

The problem is when I'm on a page that use (.sec1), this (#jqueryLoader) preloader also ran.

I wrote the code below but still the problem is not resolved.

```
 function ajaxStart() {
        $("#jqueryLoader").css('display', 'none');
        $(".sec1").show();
    }

function load_Preloader() { 
        $.ajax({
              ajaxStart: window['ajaxStart'];
              $(".sec1").css('position', 'absolute');
              $(".sec1").css('z-index', '10000');
              $("#jqueryLoader").css('display', 'none');
         });
    }

load_Preloader();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found The Answer :

```
function load_Preloader() { 
    $.ajax({
          ajaxstart: ajaxStart(),
          $(".sec1").css('position', 'absolute');
          $(".sec1").css('z-index', '10000');
          $("#jqueryLoader").css('display', 'none');
     });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function load_Preloader(id) { 
    $.ajax({
          ajaxStart: window['ajaxStart'];
          if(id){
            $("#jqueryLoader").css('display', 'none');
          }else{
            $(".sec1").css('position', 'absolute');
            $(".sec1").css('z-index', '10000');
          }
     });
}

load_Preloader(0); // adds #jqueryLoader
//or
load_Preloader(1); //adds .sec1
```